# How to do authorization with CanCan when I have a User and a separate Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

My application uses to different Models to manage Users and Admins. What is the best way to implement authorization using CanCan for each of these Models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to test what type of object is being used for authorization in your cancan abilities file.

Something like the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user_or_admin)

    case user_or_admin.class.name
    when 'User'
      can :read, :post
    when 'Admin'
      can :manage, :all
    else
      user = User.new # guest user
      # ... other permissions for guests
    end

  end
end
```